# Convert an object System.Data.Linq.DataQuery to System.Linq.IQueryable?

Tags: vb.net, linq, iqueryable

How can I convert an object of type `System.Data.Linq.DataQuery` to `System.Linq.IQueryable`?

I'm working with Visual Basic/Silverlight, and the source code of my query is as follows:

```
Public Function Get_Cli_Pag() As IQueryable(Of V_Cliente_Pagare) 

    Dim Qry = From P In Me.Context.Pagares Join C In Me.Context.Codigos On C.Codigo 
        Equals P.Tipo_Pagare Where P.Nulo = 0 And P.Extraviado = 0 And C.Clave = 5 Select P.Rut, P.Cliente.Nombre, P.Tipo_Pagare, Tipo_Pagare_Descripcion = C.Descripcion, P.Pagare 

    Return Qry.AsQueryable 
End Function
```

Comment: Could you provide a code example of what you're trying to do? How are you creating your DataQuery? Are you using VB or C#?

Comment: I'm working with Visual Basic/SilverLigth and the source code of my query is as follows

    Public Function Get_Cli_Pag() As IQueryable(Of V_Cliente_Pagare)
        Dim Qry = From P In Me.Context.Pagares Join C In Me.Context.Codigos On C.Codigo Equals P.Tipo_Pagare Where P.Nulo = 0 And P.Extraviado = 0 And C.Clave = 5 Select P.Rut, P.Cliente.Nombre, P.Tipo_Pagare, Tipo_Pagare_Descripcion = C.Descripcion, P.Pagare
        Return Qry.AsQueryable
    End Function

Sincerely
Leonardo Moreno Flores.

Comment: Let me back up and say "Welcome to StackOverflow!" You should edit your question and place the source code in the question. That will make it much more readable than placing code here in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Does the .AsQueryable extension method work?

Comment: I'm working with Visual Basic/SilverLigth and the source code of my query is as follows 

Public Function Get_Cli_Pag() As IQueryable(Of V_Cliente_Pagare) Dim Qry = From P In Me.Context.Pagares Join C In Me.Context.Codigos On C.Codigo Equals P.Tipo_Pagare Where P.Nulo = 0 And P.Extraviado = 0 And C.Clave = 5 Select P.Rut, P.Cliente.Nombre, P.Tipo_Pagare, Tipo_Pagare_Descripcion = C.Descripcion, P.Pagare Return Qry.AsQueryable 
End Function 

Sincerely 
Leonardo Moreno Flores.